# Vertex AI Pipeline is failing while trying to get data from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run a Google Vertex AI pipeline to query from a BigQuery table. In the pipeline, I am using the right project and the service account(which has bigquery.jobs.create access). But I see when it runs, it is accessing another project e1cd7306fb577e88gq-uq. I am not able to figure out where from this project is coming from. I am running the pipeline from Vertex AI user managed notebook

```
pandas_gbq.exceptions.GenericGBQException: Reason: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/e1cd7306fb577e88gq-uq/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Access Denied: Project e1cd7306fb577e88gq-uq: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project e1cd7306fb577e88gq-uq.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service agent or service account running your code does have the required permission, but your code is trying to access a resource in the wrong project. Due to the way Vertex AI runs your training code, this problem can occur inadvertently if you don't explicitly specify a project ID or project number in your code.

You can explicitly select the project you want this way:

```
import os

from google.cloud import bigquery

project_number = os.environ["CLOUD_ML_PROJECT_ID"]

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_number)
```

You can read more about training code requirements [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/code-requirements#other-services).

Comment: I actually followed this also. But it did not work

Comment: It worked, I was putting the project id at the wrong place. It should be data = pd.read_gbq(query=sql, project_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",use_bqstorage_api=True)